# How to put multiple forms in the same page using joomla?

Tags: forms, joomla, content-management-system

I'm using CKForms to create 3 forms, so far, they are independent components, I would like to put them in the same page.

This manual could help :
http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/12021/48586/manual_ckforms-EN-1.3.4.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use **multiple instances of the same component** in a joomla page, you have to check if there is a module or a plugin available.

If there is an option for a module you could publish each instance in a module position.

If there is a plugin, you could create an article (or a module in some cases) and add plugin code to load plugin instance.

Checking CKForms site I could see that there are both options.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you @emmanuel. this manual was helpful : http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/12021/48586/manual_ckforms-EN-1.3.4.pdf